# Google Analytics report by section of the website

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics is it possible to report unique pageviews by section of the website, where a section may contain one or more known pages?
For example:

HomePage:

- Red section =75%
- Blue section  =25%

Level 2:

- Red a(10% of 75%)
- Red b(90% of 75%)
- Blue a(20% of 25%)
- Blue b(80% of 25%)

Level 3:

- Red a 1(30% of 10% of 75%)
- Red a 2(70% of 10% of 75%)
- Red b 1(50% of 90% of 75%)
- Red b 2(50% of 90% of 75%)
- Blue a 1(40% of 20% of 25%)
- Blue a 2(60% of 20% of 25%)
- Blue b 1(60% of 80% of 25%)
- Blue b 2(40% of 80% of 25%)

Comment: HomePage:
    Red section =75%
    Blue section =25%
What do you mean by section here? What is red, what is blue section?